# Query for two models at once with Ajax - Eloquent - Laravel

Tags: ajax, laravel, eloquent

I would like to be able to list the records of two models at the same time, taking into account how I have the query set up at the moment to use it with Ajax.

Right now my query works fine, considering the rest of my project (AJAX - Laravel).

```
public function allData(){
        $data = Siniestro::orderBy('id','DESC')->get();
        return response()->json($data);
    }
```

I've tried doing it like this, but it looks like I'm doing the query wrong

```
public function allData(){
    $data = Siniestro::orderBy('id','DESC')->get();
    $users = User::all();
    return response()->json($data, $users);
}
```

Edit:

[Esta es la vista que estoy refiriendo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pGmul.png)

This is the view; I want that with the eloquent query, it shows me ordered as now (orderBy), and also that it looks for a match of fields with "where"; for example $siniestros = Siniestro::where('estado', 'coordinado')->get();.

Edit 2

[dd($users)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WYwqt.png)

full view code

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
    <section class="section">
        <div class="section-header">
            <h3 class="page__heading">Derivar IP</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="section-body">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-9">
                    <div class="card">
                        <div class="card-header">                          
                                Inspecciones coordinadas                        
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <table class="table table-sm m-1 p-1 table-bordered table-hover table-striped tablita" style="width:100%">
                                <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <!-- <th scope="col">#</th> -->
                                        <th scope="col">Siniestro</th>
                                        <th scope="col">Fecha IP</th>
                                        <th scope="col">Modalidad</th>
                                        <th scope="col">Dirección</th>
                                        <th scope="col">Localidad</th>
                                        <th scope="col">Inspector</th>                                    
                                        <th scope="col">Acciones</th>
                                        
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>

                                </tbody>
                            </table> 
                            
                            
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-3" style="position:fixed; bottom:550px; right:0px">
                    <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-header">                          
                                <span id="addT">Asignar IP</span>
                                <span id="updateT">Asignar IP</span>                         
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-body">
                                    

                                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label for="inspector">Inspector</label>
                                            <input type="text" name="inspector" class="form-control"  id="inspector" for="inspector" >
                                            <span class="text-danger" id="instituteError"></span>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>


                                    <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3">
                                    <label for="inspector">Inspector</label>
                                    <select class="form-select col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12" aria-label="Default select example" for="inspector" name="inspector" >
                                            <option selected></option>
                                            
                                            <option value="Taller del asegurado">Taller del asegurado</option>
                                            
                                        </select>
                                    </div>





                                    <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                                <label for="emailperito">E-mail</label>
                                                <input type="text" name="emailperito"  class="form-control" id="emailperito" for="emailperito">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                                <label for="telefonoperito">Teléfono</label>
                                                <input type="text" name="telefonoperito"  class="form-control" id="telefonoperito" for="telefonoperito">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                    

                                    

                                    <input type="hidden" id="id">
                                    
                                    <button type="submit" id="updateButton" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" onclick="updateData(event)">Asignar</button>
                                                      
                                                        
                        </div>
                        
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
    
    

@endsection


@section('javas')

  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.tablita').DataTable({
        "serverSide": true,
        "ajax": "/teacher/all",
        "columns": [
            // {data: 'id'},
            {data: 'siniestro'},
            {data: 'fechaip'},
            {data: 'modalidad'},
            {data: 'direccion'},
            {data: 'localidad'},
            {data: 'inspector'},
            {data: 'action', name: 'action', orderable: true, searchable: true},
            
            

            
            
        ],

        
    });
})
</script>  

<script>



    





 $('#addT').hide();
 $('#addButton').hide();
 $('#updateT').show();
 $('#updateButton').show();

$.ajaxSetup({
    headers:{
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
})

//---------------------------------------------- Llamar datos de la BD ---------------------------------------------------------------

function allData(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        url: "/teacher/all",
        success: function (response){
            var data = ""
            $.each(response, function(key, value){
                data = data + "<tr>"
                // data = data + "<td>"+value.id+"</td>"
                data = data + "<td>"+value.siniestro+"</td>"
                data = data + "<td>"+value.fechaip+"</td>"
                data = data + "<td>"+value.modalidad+"</td>"
                data = data + "<td>"+value.direccion+"</td>"
                data = data + "<td>"+value.localidad+"</td>"
                data = data + "<td>"+value.inspector+"</td>"
                data = data + "<td>"
                data = data + "<button class='btn btn-info btn-sm' onclick='editData("+value.id+")'>Asignar IP</button>"
                data = data + "</td>"
                data = data + "</tr>"
            })
            $('tbody').html(data);
        }
    })
}

// --------------------------------------------- fin de llamar datos de la DB ----------------------------------------------------------

allData();

// --------------------------------------------- Limpiar los campos despues del submit -------------------------------------------------

function clearData(){
 $('#siniestro').val('');
 $('#fechaip').val('');
 $('#inspector').val('');
 $('#nameError').text('');
 $('#titleError').text('');
 $('#instituteError').text('');

}

// --------------------------------------------- fin de limpiar los campos despues del submit -------------------------------------------------

// --------------------------------------------- Agregar registros a la table de BD -------------------------------------------------


function addData(){
    var siniestro = $('#siniestro').val();
    var fechaip = $('#fechaip').val();
    var inspector = $('#inspector').val();

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "Json",
        data: {siniestro:siniestro, fechaip:fechaip, inspector:inspector},
        url:"/teacher/store/",
        success: function(data){
            allData();
            clearData();
            console.log('datos agregados con éxito');
        },

        error: function(error){
            $('#nameError').text(error.responseJSON.errors.name);
            $('#titleError').text(error.responseJSON.errors.title);
            $('#instituteError').text(error.responseJSON.errors.institute);
            
        }
    })

}

// --------------------------------------------- fin de agregar registros a la table de BD -------------------------------------------------
// --------------------------------------------- Editar registros a la table de BD ---------------------------------------------------------

function editData(id){
    



 
      $.ajax({
          type:"get",
          dataType:"json",
          url:"/teacher/edit/"+id,
          success: function(data){
             $('#addT').hide();
             $('#addButton').hide();
             $('#updateT').show();
             $('#updateButton').show();

              $('#id').val(data.id);
            //   $('#siniestro').val(data.siniestro);
            //   $('#fechaip').val(data.fechaip);
              $('#inspector').val(data.inspector);
             

              console.log(data);
          }
      })
 }

 // --------------------------------------------- Fin de editar registros a la table de BD -------------------------------------------------
 // --------------------------------------------- Update de registros a la table de BD -----------------------------------------------------



 function updateData(event){

    event.preventDefault();
     var id = $('#id').val();
    //  var siniestro =  $('#siniestro').val();
    //  var fechaip = $('#fechaip').val();
     var inspector = $('#inspector').val();

     $.ajaxSetup({
    headers:{
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
})
     

     $.ajax({
         type: "PUT",
         dataType: "json",
         data: {inspector:inspector},
         url: "/teacher/update/"+id,
         success: function(response){
            allData();
            clearData();
         console.log('Siniestro asignado con éxito');
         }
         
     })


 }

 


</script>
@endsection
```

Edit 3

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qf63K.png)

See, the previous capture that showed me the attributes was only from $users, now using $data = Siniestro::orderBy('fechaip','ASC')->get();$users = User::all();$combo = ['users' => $users, 'data' => $data];dd($combo); As you can see, it shows me all the users, but I can't see their "attributes", strange, right? will the problem be there?

Comment: What's the error you are getting? It's not clear what you are trying to achieve and what is not working.

Comment: I want to pass more than one condition in this query. I have tried to do it as indicated above, but the data in the Datatable is loaded with an error, appearing as undefined.

Comment: It's still not clear what you want to achieve. Post the code of the view where you want to display the data. Probably then it may be clear what data you want in view and what is the mismatch in the controller action.

Comment: y edit, and add a picture!

Comment: This image is not useful to understand the issue. Please post the code for the view, even if its a javascript framework (like React or Vue) component - actual code (markup and javascript or blade view file) of the view which is used to display the image. Without the code it is difficult to understand where the issue arises.

Comment: @Donkarnash i add mi full view code. Is Laravel 9.

Comment: @Donkarnash i update the post, see news whit new pic!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So when you do

```php
$data = Siniestro::orderBy('fechaip','ASC')->get();
$users = User::all();
$combo = ['users' => $users, 'data' => $data];

return response()->json($combo);
```

Then you should inspect the incoming response data in your javascript. As now the data is keyed by `data` and `users`. So in your `allData()` function in javascript you will have to adjust as per the keys to display the data.

```js
function allData(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        url: "/teacher/all",
        success: function (response){

            //Here console.log(response) to see the structure of incoming data
            console.log(response)
            // Should output something like
            // {users: [... array of user records(objects)], data: [... array of siniestro records (objects)}
           
            // So to generate the display markup you may have to do
            $siniestroMarkup = "";
            $.each(response.data, function(key, value){
                siniestroMarkup = siniestroMarkup + "<tr>"
                siniestroMarkup = siniestroMarkup + "<td>"+value.id+"</td>"
                siniestroMarkup = siniestroMarkup + "<td>"+value.siniestro+"</td>"
                siniestroMarkup = siniestroMarkup + "<td>"+value.fechaip+"</td>"
                siniestroMarkup = siniestroMarkup + "<td>"+value.modalidad+"</td>"
                siniestroMarkup = siniestroMarkup + "<td>"+value.direccion+"</td>"
                siniestroMarkup = siniestroMarkup + "<td>"+value.localidad+"</td>"
                siniestroMarkup = siniestroMarkup + "<td>"+value.inspector+"</td>"
                siniestroMarkup = siniestroMarkup + "<td>"
                siniestroMarkup = siniestroMarkup + "<td>"
                siniestroMarkup = siniestroMarkup + "<button class='btn btn-info btn-sm' onclick='editData("+value.id+")'>Asignar IP</button>"
                siniestroMarkup = siniestroMarkup + "</td>"
                siniestroMarkup = siniestroMarkup + "</tr>"
            })
            $('tbody').html(siniestroMarkup);
        });

            // Similarly you can access the user records
         $.each(response.users, function(key, value) {
            //Here value will represent each user record
         });

}
```

And you may also have to adjust the `DataTable` ajax response if you are using it probably like below (check exact response data structure for and how to access it for DataTable)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.tablita').DataTable({
        "serverSide": true,
        "ajax": "/teacher/all",
        "columns": [
            // {data: 'id'},
            {data: 'data.siniestro'},
            {data: 'data.fechaip'},
            {data: 'data.modalidad'},
            {data: 'data.direccion'},
            {data: 'data.localidad'},
            {data: 'data.inspector'},
            {data: 'data.action', name: 'action', orderable: true, searchable: true},              
        ],
    });
})
```

Check the above and see if that's how you want the data.

Comment: Hi! The issue is that I don't want to pull data from $users to display in the table... but I want, in the form I have, do a @foreach($users as $users) in a <select> in <div class="col-sm-3"... to take these data dynamically, and perhaps get the user's name, phone and mail...

Comment: So in that case you have two options: **One:** Use a library like `select2` with jQuery for the users selection using the json response `data.users` or **Two:** Create a new route to fetch data for the `DataTable` and return a blade view from your current Controller method with `$users` to populate the select option via `@foreach` loop in blade

Comment: tnx buddy. i make other function, and add multiple parameters now :)

Answer (score 0):

json as a rule will always post an array, you can not post individual objects that way. you need to convert the objects into an array and post it.

```
$response_array['message'] = $data;
                $response_array['data'] = $users;
                return response()->json($response_array);
```

or

$data = ['users' => $users, 'content' => $contents];
return response()->json($data);

You can receive those data using :

```
success: function(response) {
console.log(response.content);
}
```

Comment: $data = Siniestro::orderBy('fechaip','ASC')->get(); $users = User::all(); $combo = ['users' => $users, 'data' => $data]; return response()->json($combo); I make this... dont work :( "Undefined variable $users"

Comment: That implied $users = User::all(); itself is undefined. Are you sure the model User is correct? Is there a proper connection to the database? Is there even any data in the database? try to run a dd($users); before the $combo declaration. if it returns nothing then there may not be anything in the database or the model itself may be unconnected.

Comment: It's very strange... the user/models is well defined, it has 16 users and I just added a screenshot... it takes me the 16 users with their data; very rare

Comment: could you please post the dd result in something other than imgur or pastebin? both are blocked in Bangladesh (dont ask,lol) and I cant change the IP in my workplace.

Comment: I understand that it is the format of this forum; I can't choose it

Comment: In that case I will try to get back to you in 8 hours or so. if the issue is not resolved by that point that is.............